# Resizing a Twitter widget based on screensize

Tags: css, twitter

So my website can resize based on screen size, but when I implemented a Twitter widget, when I tried resizing it, the widget, despite having the attribute `width:'auto'` did not resize.  Here is the code for the widget:

```
<script charset="utf-8" src="http://widgets.twimg.com/j/2/widget.js"></script>
<script>
new TWTR.Widget({
  version: 2,
  type: 'profile',
  rpp: 2,
  interval: 30000,
  width: 'auto',
  height: 100,
  theme: {
    shell: {
      background: '#dbdbdb',
      color: '#000000'
    },
    tweets: {
      background: '#dbdbdb',
      color: '#000000',
      links: '#000000'
    }
  },
  features: {
    scrollbar: true,
    loop: false,
    live: false,
    behavior: 'all'
  }
}).render().setUser('jackstonedev').start();
</script>
```

And here is the CSS for the widget:

```
#twittercontainer
{
    border:3px solid;
    border-radius:20px;
    background-color:lightgrey;
    opacity:0.7;
    max-width:500px;
    margin: auto;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try resizing by using % instead of auto.

If the parent div then resizes your widget should aswel, for example if you set your widgets css to

```
#widget { width: 90%; }
```

if the parent div is 100 pixels wide, your widget will be 90 pixels wide.
I Hope this works for you.

What might also be a problem is that if the twitter widget is loaded via iFrame / or JS generated, it might assign CSS values aswel, these can override your own set values since they are set when/after the page is loaded. Try inspecting the widget itself in the HTML source and see what is happening to it.

Answer (score 2):

Annoyingly you can't do this with the new twitter widgets and the old API is due to be binned in march 2013 but I wrote some stuff on how to solve it using the new widgets here using jquery albeit a fairly simplistic approach:
http://tappetyclick.com/blog/2012/12/20/how-dynamically-resize-new-twitter-widget

Answer (score 0):

put widget in wrapper and change width to
width: '100%',

it should work as you expect.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to change the width of two widgets to 100% in my Rails application by adding the following code in my stylesheet:

```
#twitter-widget-0, #twitter-widget-1 {

  float: none;
  width: 100% !important; 

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I used this:

```
$('#twitter-widget-0').height($('#ID_SIMILAR HEIGHT').height());
```

Comment: … what does that have to do with the width?